# Parsing multidimensional json string in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

is there an efficient plugin to parse a multidimensional json string in MySQL the same way you can do it in MSSQL?

```
{ something : 
    [{ somethingElse :
        [{ awesome : true }]
    }],
    [{ somethingDifferent :
        [{ awesome : false, moreAwesome : true }]
    }]
}
```

Using common schema is way from perfect. It fails when the json key does not have a letter, fails when the json is multidimensional etc.

Splitting the JSON in PHP is not the option for us unless it is not possible to do this at all / MySQL performance would suffer much.

Thanks

Comment: MySQL is a relational database and it's job is to store **structured data**. What you're doing is turning it into a glorified text file that can parse JSON. Sadly, that's not what MySQL is for. It's like using an airplane to deliver ice cream to your neighbor - you just don't use airplanes for that. You can but it's an overkill. Also, your statement that performance would suffer if you parse JSON in a third-party system (PHP or some other language) has no basis really. Alternatively, you can search MySQL UDF repository for a JSON library if you really want to do things wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using something like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/). It was built for storing and working with JSON-data.

To use MySQL efficiently, you'll need to restructure the data in a two dimensional relational way, before inserting it into the database.